# OpenCV connects boundarys of image with detected objects

Tags: python, opencv, find, border, detection

I am working with OpenCV to detect some cracks in a picture. The picture is a .TIF file because it is from a microscope. There are multiple cracks in the picture, which are being detected. BUT the borders are connected to some of the detected objects, combining them to a very large detected object/'crack'.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

src = cv.imread('cracks.TIF', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

ret, th1 = cv.threshold(src, 95, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
closing = cv.morphologyEx(th1, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(closing, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

overlay = src.copy()
cont = cv.drawContours(overlay, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

titles = ["ORIGINAL", "THRESH_BINARY", "CLOSING" , "CONTOURS"]
images = [src, th1, closing, overlay]

for i in range(len(images)):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1), plt.imshow(images[i])
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

This is the output:

[image: Crack detection]

And when I zoom in on the crack detection, there the script detects the borders also and connects it to the cracks that are cut from the image:

[image: border detected]

I uploaded the image so you can try it yourself with my script.

https://ufile.io/slbfwn38

I have tried some different things but I can't get it to work properly. I think I am missing something fundamental on how OpenCV operates but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not related to the boundaries, but related to the fact that `findContours` finds white contours (and not black contours).

`th1` is almost entirely white, so it is detected as one large contour.

- Replace `cv.THRESH_BINARY` with `cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV` for inverting black and white in `th1`:

  ```
   ret, th1 = cv.threshold(src, 95, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
  ```
- Replace closing morphological operation with opening (opening is the equivalent to closing when black and white are inverted):

  ```
   opening = cv.morphologyEx(th1, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

src = cv.imread('cracks.TIF', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

ret, th1 = cv.threshold(src, 95, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
#closing = cv.morphologyEx(th1, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
opening = cv.morphologyEx(th1, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)  # Use opening instead of closing because of inverted black/white

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(opening, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#overlay = src.copy()
overlay = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)  # Convert to BGR before drawing contours
cont = cv.drawContours(overlay, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)  # Draw contours with green color

titles = ["ORIGINAL", "THRESH_BINARY", "OPENING" , "CONTOURS"]
images = [src, th1, opening, overlay]

for i in range(len(images)):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1), plt.imshow(images[i])
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

---

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That did explain everything I asked for.